# T-SQL Merging two items from the same column together

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, items

For a project I have a list of users. My task is to couple users together. So for instance:

```
Ind   Name
1.    Mary
2.    Jacob
3.    James
4.    Karin
```

I have looked for ways to merge them, but most google SQL merge questions are about merging columns not specific items, let alone just two. The result I am trying to achieve is a new table where I store the possible couples as follows:

```
Ind   Couple
1.    Jacob + Mary
2.    James + Jacob
3.    James + Mary
4.    Karin + James
5.    Karin + Jacob
6.    Karin + Mary
```

Is this possible in SQL or do I have to develop some workaround with a PHP script where I get the data and manipulate it with PHP or Javascript and than return it to the new table?

Thanks in advance for anyone that can help.
P.S. I was told the server uses Microsoft or T-SQL

Answer (score 1):

You can use a self join:

```
select u.name, u2.name
from users u join
     users u2
     on u.ind < u2.ind
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I am guessing that u is a variable of the tableId or Ind in my example. Is this automated? Or would this only do the first 2 Indexes?

Comment: @Guyke . . . `u` is a table aliases.  Based on the question, I assumed the table is named `users`.

Answer (score 1):

This reads like a self-join:

```
select t1.name name1, t2.name name2
from mytable t1
inner join mytable t2 on t1.name < t2.name
```

You can put both names in a single column with string concatenation, like:

```
select concat(t1.name, ' + ', t2.name) as couple
from mytable t1
inner join mytable t2 on t1.name < t2.name
```

Comment: Thank you for the amazing help. This is exactly what I was looking for. I realized after trying Gordon Linoff's code that his solution would be even less data. So I am going with his solution. But for anyone looking for an answer to my question the above code of GMB is exactly what you need.